# SQL query to repeat each row n times and add to it, data from another table

Tags: mysql

I have one SQL query with result table having a list of 700 userids and the corresponding gameids (games played by the user; there are totally 1000 games).

One user might have played more than one games and one gameid may be associated with more than one userid. I have another table in the database that has the list of all gameids and their respective attributes.

I want my final result table to be like: column 1 with all 700 userids (each repeated as many times as the number of  gameids associated with the user) and column 2 with the corresponding gameids AND other gameids from the gameid table. These other gameids against each userid should be different from the ones already placed against the userid.

**table1**

```
Userid      Gameid    
1              3    
1              4    
2             63    
2             76    
6             99    
6             63
```

**table2**

```
Gameid     gamename
1           GTA    
2           DOTA    
1000        xyz
```

**result table**

```
Userid  Gameid       Gamename
1         3          AOE    
1         4          Roadrash    
1         1          GTA    
1         2          DOTA    
1         5          qbc     
so on up to 
1       1000         xyz
```

similarly for all userids from table1.

Result table has each user id repeated 1000 times and the top n gameids against each userid are the ones from table1(games the particular users have played) and the rest of the gameids are from the 1000 from table 2(therefore each user is mapped against all the gameids with the top ones being the games they've played).

The idea of the data set up is to include a column in the end of the result table that has binary values (1 -> user has played the game, 0 -> user has not played the game). This table is to be used for machine learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build the result table as a union of the games played by users and the games not played by users like so:

```
  select UserId, GameId, GameName, Played
  from (
    -- games played
    select usr.UserId, gme.GameId, gme.GameName, 1 as Played
    from USERS usr
    inner join GAMES gme on usr.GameId = gme.GameId
    union
    -- games not played
    select usr.UserId, gme.GameId, gme.GameName, 0 as played
    from USERS usr, GAMES gme
    where gme.GameId not in (
      select usr2.GameId
      from USERS usr2
       where usr2.UserId = usr.UserId
    )
  )
  order by Userid, Played desc, Gameid
```

The outer select is used to order the results set such that games played are provided first.

Comment: The code works. Thank you! May I know why we can't just say not in ( select usr.GameId from users ) in the last section of the code? Also, is there a way to consider just 700 games ( not the top 700 from the list but a total of 700 which includes the games played and not played by the users) ? This is because I have to export it to excel and it doesn't accommodate as many rows. So for the last few users, only the games played is being accommodated by excel. The number of rows returned in the result table is 4685400!

Comment: To idea for the second query -- the query that retrieves the games not played -- is to retain the the record in the GAMES table that are not references in the USERS table for a given user. Therefore, the USERS table must be referenced twice, one time to define the current user (usr alias) and one time to get the games played by the current user (usr2 alias). The list of games can be narrowed down by adding a 'where' clause on the outer query 'where GameId in (...)'.

Comment: Okay. Just one last thing. I am trying to display the names of the users as well. but when I inner join this section of code (excluding the outer query since order is not important) with the appusers table, it shows only 50000 rows, just the top 11 users. I just named the games played and not played section of codes as result1 and inner joined it with appusers table based on users.userid=appusers.id. Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Also, when I include where clause at the end, the result table does not include cases where userid=1 and gameid=800 (basically if a user has played a game with id above 700, it is not included)

Comment: To include the name of the user (assuming the name is in the USERS table), simply add usr.UserName in the select portion of each of the 2 parts of the union.

Comment: I am not clear on how the list of 700 games to include is defined. If you have this list in a table, you can add a condition to each sub query: where GameId in (select GameId from GamesToInclude)

Comment: The names of the users are not in the users table. users table is actually players table with ids of players and the games they have played. Theres  another table called appusers that has the list of all users and their attributes. Somehow when I join the result set with appusers table,it returns only 50000 rows that includes only 11 users

Comment: but when I say where userid=812, it did show the list for that user. For some reason it doesn't display for all users at once. just 50000 rows.

Comment: The 50,000 rows limit may just be a limitation of the tool you are using to run the SQL. Try select count(*) ... to get the total number of rows returned by the query. Also, if for some reason USERS has users not included in APPUSERS, joining with limit the results. To avoid, this issue, use and outer join to APPUSERS rather than an inner join.

Comment: Oh no. users has a subset of the list of users in appusers. users has only the list of users who have played. appusers has more users( even users who haven't played any game at all).

Comment: You were right about the limitation of the tool. The query works fine.

Comment: Looks like there is something wrong with the games not played part of the code. It does return the games not played by particular users. But, it also returns games played by the users. So the result table has user1---gameid6---1(played or not column) and also theres a record like user1----gameid6---0(played or not column). So the result set from the first query are being repeated in the second but with 0 in the last column. How do I get rid of those records?

Comment: Would have to see the exact query that you are running. When I try it using simple test data, the results are as I would expect.

Comment: I'm sorry, I used the wrong field name. The code works perfectly fine. However, I have about 6000 entries in the games table and 700 users. Each user against the games they have played and all the rest of the games they haven't played would make the result set so large that it can't be exported to cvs completely. Is there a way to tweak the code such that each user is mapped against all the games they have played and just some (may be 50) of the games they haven't played? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use 'top' directive to limit the number of rows returned by the second query. Something like this: 
select top 50 usr.UserId, gme.GameId, gme.GameName, 0 as played